# Cache flask-login current_user.is_authenticated

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-login

If I have a template with multiples validations of `{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}` it makes sense to use something like this to minimize the overhead and then just check `current_user_is_authenticated` ?

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    {% set current_user_is_authenticated = True %}
{% else %}
    {% set current_user_is_authenticated = False %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is up to you how you implement `is_authenticated` method on the user class.
By default it always just return `True` for current user if he is logged in.

Answering you question: if you don't have custom `is_authenticated` method implementation then there is not a single thing to minimize overhead. However if you query db, make external api calls etc. in `is_authenticated` it would be some kind of optimization to store its return value in variable when using it multiple times in the template.